# ReactJs Unable to setSate in componentDidMount from async function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I'm calling an async function (`getData()`) in `componentDidMount`, and I'm trying to use `this.setState` with result of that function.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let newData = getData();
    newPodData.then(function (result) {
      console.log('result', result)
      this.setState({result})
    })
  }
```

However, I'm having issues getting my state to properly update. Some additional context - I'm trying to set my initial state with data I am receiving from a database. Is my current approach correct? What's the best way to accomplish this?  Here's my async function for more context:

```
const getTeamData = async () => {

    const getTeamMembers = async () => {
        let res = await teamMemberService.getTeamMembers().then(token => { return token });
        return res;
    }

    const getActiveTeams = async () => {
        let res = await teamService.getActiveTeams().then(token => { return token });
        return res;
    }

    const teamMemberResult = await getTeamMembers()
    const activeTeamsResult = await getActiveTeams();

    // get team member data and add to teamMember object
    let teamMemberData = teamMemberResult.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc.teamMembers[curr.id] = curr;
        return acc;
      }, {
        teamMembers: {}
      });

    // get team ids and add to teamOrder array
    let activeTeamsData = activeTeamsResult.map(team => team.id)

    let key = 'teamOrder'
    let obj = []
    obj[key] = activeTeamsData;

    const newObject = Object.assign(teamMemberData, obj)

    return newObject;
}

export default getTeamData;
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the function inside the `then` handler to an arrow function should fix it. e.g:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    let newData = getData();
    newPodData.then((result) => {
      console.log('result', result)
      this.setState({result})
    })
  }
```

But I'll like to suggest a better way to write that.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    let result = await getData();
    this.setState({result})
  }
```